# Can we apply a char_filter to a custom tokenizer in elasticsearch?

Tags: elasticsearch

I have set up a custom analyser in Elasticsearch that uses an edge-ngram tokeniser and I'm experimenting with filters and char_filters to refine the search experience.

I've been pointed to the excellent tool [elyser](https://github.com/o19s/elyzer) which enables you to test the affect your custom analyser has on a specific term but this is throwing errors when I combine a custom analyser with a char_filter, specifically html_strip.

The error I get from elyser is:

> illegal_argument_exception', 'reason': 'Custom normalizer may not use
>   char filter [html_strip]'

I would like to know whether this is a legitimate error message or whether it represents a bug in the tool.

I've referred to the main documentation and even their [custom analyser](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-custom-analyzer.html) example throws an error in elyser:

```
PUT my_index
{
  "settings": {
    "analysis": {
      "analyzer": {
        "my_custom_analyzer": {
          "type":      "custom", 
          "tokenizer": "standard",
          "char_filter": [
            "html_strip"
          ],
          "filter": [
            "lowercase",
            "asciifolding"
          ]
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Command in elyser:

```
elyzer --es "http://localhost:9200" --index my_index --analyzer my_custom_analyzer "Trinity Chapel <h1>[in fact King's Chapel]</h1>"
```

If it turns out that elyser is at fault, could anyone point me to an alternative method of examining the tokens produced from my custom analyser so that I can test the impact of each filter?

My custom analysers look a little bit like I've thrown the kitchen sink at them and I'd like a way to test and refactor:

```
PUT /objects
{
  "settings" : {
    "index" : {
      "number_of_shards" : "5",
      "analysis" : {
        "analyzer" : {
          "search_autocomplete": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "standard",
            "char_filter" : [
              "html_strip"
            ],
            "filter": [
              "standard",
              "apostrophe",
              "lowercase",
              "asciifolding",
              "english_stop",
              "english_stemmer"
          ] 
          },
          "autocomplete": {
            "type": "custom",
            "tokenizer": "autocomplete",
            "filter": [
                "standard",
                "lowercase",
                "asciifolding",
                "english_stop",
                "english_stemmer"
            ]
          },
          "title_html_strip" : {
            "filter" : [
              "standard",
              "lowercase"
            ],
            "char_filter" : [
              "html_strip"
            ],
            "type" : "custom",
            "tokenizer" : "standard"
          }
        },
        "tokenizer": {
          "autocomplete": {
            "type": "edge_ngram",
            "min_gram": 3,
            "max_gram": 20,
            "token_chars": [
              "letter",
              "digit"
            ]
          }
        },
        "filter": {
          "english_stop": {
            "type": "stop",
            "stopwords": "_english_"
          },
          "english_stemmer": {
            "type": "stemmer",
            "name": "english"
          }
        }
      }
    }
  }
}
```

Comment: it's funny that you get an error about a "normalizer", even though you're defining an "analyzer"

Comment: Yes its odd, perhaps I should raise it as an issue / question on the github page for elyser

Comment: The error message you get comes back from ES, not elyzer, so maybe we need to understand first

Comment: Which version of Elyzer, respectively ES, are you using?

Comment: I didn't know about the source of the error message and I can't seem to replicate it outside of elyser. I am using ES6 from the docker image oss:6.5.4 and for elyzer I'm not sure how to tell - I installed it today if that helps?

Comment: I think it may be v1.2

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This bug is in elyzer. In order to show the state of the tokens at each step of the analysis process, elyzer performs an analyze query for each stage: [first char filters](https://github.com/o19s/elyzer/blob/master/elyzer/elyzer.py#L86-L91), then [tokenizer](https://github.com/o19s/elyzer/blob/master/elyzer/elyzer.py#L94-L97), and finally [token filters](https://github.com/o19s/elyzer/blob/master/elyzer/elyzer.py#L100-L112).

The problem is that on ES side, the analysis process has changed since they introduced [normalizers](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/current/analysis-normalizers.html) (in a non-backward compatible way). [They assume](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/e37a0ef84425ac7497ae4de9439220811fccdfc9/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/analyze/TransportAnalyzeAction.java#L217-L220) that if there is no normalizer, no analyzer and no tokenizer in the request but either a token filter or a char_filter, then the analyze request should behave like a normalizer.

In your case, elyzer will first perform a request for the `html_strip` character filter and ES will think it is about a normalizer, hence [the error you're getting](https://github.com/elastic/elasticsearch/blob/e37a0ef84425ac7497ae4de9439220811fccdfc9/server/src/main/java/org/elasticsearch/action/admin/indices/analyze/TransportAnalyzeAction.java#L578-L583) since `html_strip` is not a valid `char_filter` for normalizers.

Since I know Elyzer's developer pretty well (Doug Turnbull), so I've [filed a bug](https://github.com/o19s/elyzer/issues/22) already. We'll see what unfolds.

Answer (score 1):

Alternative method of examining the tokens produced from my custom analysers:

The official documentation includes a section on using the [_analyse method](https://www.elastic.co/guide/en/elasticsearch/reference/6.6/indices-analyze.html) which along with the explain: true flag, provides me with the information I need to scrutinise my custom analysers.

The following outputs the tokens at each filter stage

```
GET objects/_analyze
{
  "analyzer" : "search_autocomplete",
  "explain" : true,
  "text" : "Trinity Chapel [in fact <h1>King's Chapel</h1>]"
}
```